# In Centos 6.4,when configure Emacs

Tags: centos, configure, emacs24

In Centos 6.4,when configure Emacs,it shows:

```
configure: error: The required function `tputs' was not found in any library.
The following libraries were tried (in order):
  libtinfo, libncurses, libterminfo, libtermcap, libcurses
Please try installing whichever of these libraries is most appropriate
for your system, together with its header files.
For example, a libncurses-dev(el) or similar package.
```

How to fix it,what's the problem in it.

Answer (score 19):

```
sudo yum install ncurses-devel
```

then `./configure` again

Answer (score 9):

Try to install `libncurses-dev` with
`bash
apt-get install libncurses-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Debian Wheezy derived distribution (CrunchBang)
Trying to install Emacs 24.5.1
Had to install libncurses5-dev, then run ./configure

```
$ sudo apt-get install ncurses-devel
...
E: Unable to locate package ncurses-devel
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```